# Why it isn't possible to type in URLs in the HUD?

Tags: unity, firefox, hud

[image]

With the Ubuntu's HUD you should be able to work faster.
But with Firefox it's not always the case.
If I type in an URL nothing happens...
so why it isn't possible to use URLs in the HUD?
...

How can I integrate Firefox's Awesome Bar into the Ubuntu's HUD?

Comment: I think that the HUD isn't meant to replace or incorporate the awesome bar. It's meant to allow you to access a program's **menu items** quickly, even if they're deeply nested.

Comment: I meant it as an extra feature... not a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, I accidently found out that you can type in the URL in the Dash-Board instead of the HUD.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu HUD support is done by the application developer. Firefox is responsible to do so. to  HUD is a replacement of menu items/commands. In firefox such menu doesn't exist.

I don't think at present you can change the HUD behavior. (If I am wrong please feel free to correct me). Anyway you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to goto the address bar.

You can send mail to    dev-apps-firefox@lists.mozilla.org.  requesting this feature.

Answer (score 1):

What HUD can do :

Instead of a nested tree of options, users will have a "**vocabulary UI**" that's **"closer to the way users think"** according to [Shuttleworth.](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/939) .

So instead of having the traditional "File," "Edit," "View" menus (and so on) we can pull down a menu to type in commands. So if I want to change preferences I'd start typing "pref" and (in theory) the HUD will suggest commands that matches that.

Which probably says it is an **Integrated Menu Utility of active Application** . Since Firefox menu don't have any such **MENU** option like `Go to URL` or `Enter the URL you want to Navigate`, **so currently in present scenario we can't go to desired URL from HUD.**

According to Unity/HUD [Wiki Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD)

> HUD is in a very early stage of development, and not ready for
>   production  use.

So if you are interested in developing such features , you probably can by joining the [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and getting involved in that project.

For further reading and references here :[Link1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD), [Link2](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2012/01/moving-away-from-menus-is-ubun.php), and [Link3](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/ubuntus-hud-light-years-beyond-any-menu-system/3535).